# Hard drive defect? Help me recover my music!

Tags: windows, hard-drive, data-recovery, fat32, ipod-classic

I've an old iPod Classic with 80 GB of Storage, suddenly it stopped showing any music. I can still access the files on it (with Windows Explorer). Copying all files is possible but it stops at a certain point. I need help, I don't have a backup of my music. Is there still something you can do? (Maybe a program which skips bad files or sth.)

I tried "chkdsk" but it stops after 4% with "Wrong Drive" (Falscher Datenträger). iTunes recognises the iPod but wants to restore to factory.

The Hard Drive is formatted with FAT32.

This is the SMART data from the drive:

```
Retracts: 16
Reallocs: 320
Pending Sectors: 192
PowerOn Hours: 1340
Start/Stops: 66331
Temp: Current 32C
Temp: Min 0C
Temp: Max 53C
```

HDD SPEC:

```
SNO: 97M4S655S
FW Revision: VQ110A
LBAs: 0x950f8b0
```

I don't have access to a Mac.

Answer (score 1):

You could try running [SpinRite](http://www.grc.com/sr/spinrite.htm) on the disk, then trying again to get the files off.

SpinRite (among other things) talks the drive's internal error correction into working better so Windows or the iPod's OS can more-easily read the files.

Comment: Is there a free Alternative? I don't want to buy a program if i'm not even sure if it works with my device...

Comment: @wayback They have a 30-day no-questions-asked refund because they have no free trial version. Buy it, try it, if it doesn't work they'll refund your money.